# What is the name of the stock Firefox tool to display HTML code for the part of the page under the mouse?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Less than month ago, by accident I discovered a nice tool in Firefox that was installed by default. I don't remember the name (probably code inspector or something like that) but I used Ctrl+Shift+I (Tools -> Webdeveloper -> Name of tool) shortcut to run it.

What was the tool? The tool worked such that when you positioned the mouse over some place in the webpage, in the tool's window you would see the HTML code for that place. Now, I my system is updated, and this tool has disappeared from my browser. I'm very disappointed. Anyone know what tool I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance,
Kuba

Comment: Sounds like the Page Inspector - a built-in feature to be enabled by default in Firefox 10 (will be released in a week). In Firefox 9 you can switch it on by changing `devtools.inspector.enabled` preference but it is probably better to just wait a week (the one in Firefox 10 is better).

Answer (score 1):

By the sound of what you are describing it was probably the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) addon, might also have been [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=search) (which in my opinion is better).

Comment: no, it was not the popular web developer nor firebug. Actually, I have got webdeveloper and when I click "Tools" in FF I see "Web Developer" twice - one is installed by default (here was the tool I'm looking for), another I added by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try right clicking on the page element and select "Inspect Element" which will enable element inspection. This will enable you to view the HTML contents of the elements under your mouse.
The name of this tool is: Page Inspector
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector